# How to change maps using a button in tableau

Tags: button, maps, visualization, tableau-api, data-analysis

I have a dashboard with all the charts and which includes a covid cases map. I also want to create death cases map and vaccines map. Now I want to create a button such that it only changes the map but doesn't affect the other charts in Tableau. How to do that?

The three maps are in three different worksheets. Please suggest me how to achieve this